# Wrapper to check permissions

Tags: javascript, geolocation, promise, async-await, android-permissions

Here is my wrapper function (`checkLocationPermission`) to check for permissions before attempting to call a function (in this case `geolocate()`). The wrapper is used to simplify error handling.

The problem is with `async` functions calling each other, as in Javascript it is not allowed.

How to make such wrapper return a valid Promise from `geolocate()` or any other function passed as param?

```
async geolocate() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        resolve(position);
      },
      (err) => {
        reject(err);
      },
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 30000, maximumAge: 3000}
    );
  });

}

async checkPermission(permission, fn) {
  var status = await Permissions.getPermissionStatus(permission);
  if (status!='authorized') {
    Errors.permissionError();
    this.resetAfterError();
    return Promise.reject("PERMISSION ERROR");
  }
  try {
    return fn();
  } catch(err) {
      Errors.internalError(err);
      this.resetAfterError();
      return Promise.reject("ERROR OTHER");
  }
}
```

Origin of the call:

```
var locationPromise = this.checkPermission('location', ()=>this.geolocate());
```

Comment: `The problem is with async functions calling each other, as in Javascript it is not allowed` not sure exactly what this means. What problems do you have with this code? Seems like `locationPromise` would be the Promise returned by `geolocate` (I'm assuming this code is inside a `class`)

Answer (score 1):

An `async` function returns a Promise. If you explicitly create a Promise object in geolocate(), there is no need to make it `async`.

Don't return Promise objects from an `async` function, if you want to reject the Promise, just throw an Error:

```js
function geolocate() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        resolve(position);
      },
      (err) => {
        reject(err);
      },
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 30000, maximumAge: 3000}
    );
  });
}

async function checkPermission(permission, fn) {
  var status = await Permissions.getPermissionStatus(permission);
  if (status!='authorized') {
    Errors.permissionError();
    this.resetAfterError();
    throw new Error("PERMISSION ERROR");
  }
  try {
    return fn();
  } catch(err) {
    Errors.internalError(err);
    this.resetAfterError();
    throw new Error("ERROR OTHER");
  }
}

checkPermission('location', ()=>geolocate()).then((locationPromise) => {
    //...
});
```